# Changing routes breaks game in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, phaser-framework

when i refresh the /game route it normally creates the game . but if i switch to another route and come back again to the same /game route. The canvas shows blank screen and my last scene in array runs , not the first scene

```
  static createGame() {
    console.log('game creation phaser called with config');
    game = new Phaser.Game(CONFIG);
    return game;
  }

  static destroyGame(game) {
    console.log("destroying game")
    game.destroy();
    game = null;
  }
}
```

i have tried to destroy game on componentwillunmount but nothing happens

here is my phaser config

```
const CONFIG = {
  type: Phaser.WEBGL,
  width: 720 * window.devicePixelRatio,
  height: 500 * window.devicePixelRatio,
  scene: [ModeSelectScene, PreLoadScene, PlayGame, GameOverScene],
  backgroundColor: 0x0c88c7,
  parent: 'game',
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    parent: 'game',
    width: 1334,
    height: 750,
  },
  physics: {
    default: 'arcade',
  },
};
```

it runs the GameOverScene first, idk why ! I have tried, but i keep getting the same blank screen with last scene being loaded( i checked in console)

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't think destroying the game is a good way, do you really need to do this ?

Comment: @nazimboudeffa thanks for replying man, but i do destroyed the game when componentWillUnmount() and then remount the game when the path changes and luckily that worked :)  it was my component mounting problem , that's why i was getting error. now it's solved

Comment: Interesting, nice to see it working